# Spilting number into digit then show them in Colum from MSD to LSD

Tags: c

im doing a number up to 8 digits but im lost on how to make a table using just loops.
so if the number was 12345678 it should show vertically
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

this is what i have it works some what i just want to use columns instead of printf \n to force it to look that way

```
enter code here

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int num, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, row, col;

do{
printf("enter a number");
scanf("%d", &num);
printf("%d\n", num);

}while (num<0);  


d1 =(num/10000000)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d1);

d2 =(num/1000000)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d2);

d3 =(num/100000)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d3);

d4 =(num/10000)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d4);

d5 =(num/1000)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d5);

d6 =(num/100)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d6);

d7 =(num/10)%10;  
printf("%d\n", d7);

d8 =num%10;  
printf("%d\n", d8);}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by columns?? You mean using an array and a loop to solve the problem? Anyhow, you have to use printf\n

Comment: I can only use Loops to solve the problem not array. And it cant show zeros when a number shorter then 8 digits.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the desired exact output for the number you used as example (`12345678`)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. You could use recursion or other methods, but this is the easiest in my opinion. Also, since your number should be with 8 digits, you should check if num>=10000000&&num<100000000

```
 int d,x=10000000;
 while(x>0)
{
   d=num/x;
   num=num%x;
   if(d!=0)
   printf("%d\n", d);
   x=x/10;
}
```

Comment: Sry i for got add its suppose to work for numbers with less then 8 digits too

Comment: well if that is the case, check only num<100000000